# Display a treemap by values and keys

Tags: java, treemap

I'm displaying a TreeMap sorted by keys currently by using Map.entrySet(). However, I want to  display the contents sorted by both values and keys. Is this possible? How would I go about it if it were?

EDIT: Rephrasing:

I'm currently displaying a treemap sorted by keys. I want to display it sorted by values initially, but if the values are the same, I want the keys displayed in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **Comparator** to sort the **Entry** objects in your map.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Entry<String, String>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, String> left, Entry<String, String> right) {
        int valueComp = left.getValue().compareTo(right.getValue());
        if (valueComp != 0)
            return valueComp;
        int keyComp = left.getKey().compareTo(right.getKey());
        return keyComp;
    }
}

@Test
public void testSorting() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> tree = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    tree.put("D", "A");
    tree.put("A", "A");
    tree.put("F", "C");
    tree.put("E", "B");
    tree.put("C", "A");
    tree.put("B", "B");
    Set<Entry<String, String>> entrySet = tree.entrySet();
    Comparator<? super Entry<String, String>> comparator = new MyComparator();
    TreeSet<Entry<String, String>> sorted = new TreeSet<Entry<String, String>>(comparator);
    sorted.addAll(entrySet);
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : sorted) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
A=A
C=A
D=A
B=B
E=B
F=C
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve - keys in a TreeMap are unique, thus if you sort the content by keys, sorting by values makes no sense. If you want to have two lists, one sorted by keys and another one by values, you can either use two TreeMaps or use a special container such as [Bimap](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.java?r=2).

Comment: I want the output to be the treemap sorted by values, but the values are not all unique, so when the values are the same then the keys which share the same values would be sorted.

Comment: Then you can just read the key-value pairs (Map.Entry objects), store them in an ArrayList and sort it using a custom comparator that only compares values.